# C#. How would I get random ID and then get the largeImgURL

Tags: c#, json, discord

I've tried a lot of things but my brain isn't working right now and I don't know what to do anymore. I have searched the internet but I haven't found anything that could help me.

I am trying to use the Hits.ID to get a random search result and get the large image URL from the Hit if you want the JSON API link so you can tell better what I'm trying to do.

**Search Command**

```
[Command("search")]
        public async Task Search(CommandContext ctx, string args)
        {
            WebClient n = new WebClient();

            var json = n.DownloadString("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=###################&q=" + args + "&image_type=photo&pretty=true");
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

            var builder = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
            {
                Color = DiscordColor.Rose,
                Description = "Search Result",
            };

            foreach (Hit hit in root.hits)
            {
                builder.WithImageUrl(hit.largeImageURL);
            }
            await ctx.RespondAsync(embed: builder.Build());
        }
```

**GET SET**

```
        public class Hit
        {
            public string largeImageURL { get; set; }
            public int webformatHeight { get; set; }
            public int webformatWidth { get; set; }
            public int likes { get; set; }
            public int imageWidth { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int user_id { get; set; }
            public int views { get; set; }
            public int comments { get; set; }
            public string pageURL { get; set; }
            public int imageHeight { get; set; }
            public string webformatURL { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public int previewHeight { get; set; }
            public string tags { get; set; }
            public int downloads { get; set; }
            public string user { get; set; }
            public int favorites { get; set; }
            public int imageSize { get; set; }
            public int previewWidth { get; set; }
            public string userImageURL { get; set; }
            public string previewURL { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public int totalHits { get; set; }
            public List<Hit> hits { get; set; }
            public int total { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I am trying to use the Hits.ID to get a random search result and then get the largeImageURL from the Hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random Hit from List of Hit, you can use Linq to get such result.

```
Hit randomHit = root.hits.ElementAt(new Random().Next(x.Count));
var randomUrl = randomHit.largeImageURL;
```

`ElementAt` gives you the element at a specific index. Using a random number between 0 and total number of Hits in that list, you can get a random Hit. Once you have that, you can get the userImageUrl of that object.

Comment: Could just use `root.hits[new Random().Next(x.Count)]`. Also, it is better to reuse the random, instead of new-ing one up.

Comment: microsoft also uses elementAt in their examples.. thought it was a better solution. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.8#examples). Op only mentioned one hit, otherwise using a variable for new Random() works